# Thread safety with ConcurrentHashMap

Tags: java, multithreading, concurrency, thread-safety

I have the following class. I use ConcurrentHashMap. I have many threads writing to the maps and a Timer that saves the data in the map every 5 minutes.
I manage to achieve thread safety by using putIfAbsent() when I write entries in the map. However, when I read from it and then remove all entries by clear() method, I want no other thread writes to map while I’m in the process of reading the map contents and then removing them. Obviously my code is not threadsafe even with synchronized(lock){}, b/c the thread that owns the lock in saveEntries(), is not necessarily the same thread that writes into my maps in log() method! Unless I lock the whole code in log() with the same lock object!

I was wondering is there any other way to achieve thread safety w/o enforcing synchronizing by an external lock? Any help is greatly appreciated.

```
public class Logging {

private static Logging instance;    
private static final String vendor1 = "vendor1";
private static final String vendor2 = "vendor2";    
private static long delay = 5 * 60 * 1000;

private ConcurrentMap<String, Event> vendor1Calls = new ConcurrentHashMap<String, Event>();
private ConcurrentMap<String, Event> vendor2Calls = new ConcurrentHashMap<String, Event>();

private Timer timer;    
private final Object lock = new Object();

private Logging(){
    timer = new Timer();                
    timer.schedule(new TimerTask() {
        public void run() {
            try {
                saveEntries();
            } catch (Throwable t) {
                timer.cancel();
                timer.purge();
            }
        }       
    }, 0, delay);
}

public static synchronized Logging getInstance(){     
    if (instance == null){
        instance = new Logging();
    }
    return instance;
 }

public void log(){      
    ConcurrentMap<String, Event> map;
    String key = "";        

    if (vendor1.equalsIgnoreCase(engine)){
        map = vendor1Calls;
    }else if(vendor2.equalsIgnoreCase(engine)){  
        map = vendor2Calls;
    }else{
        return;
    }       


    key = service + "." + method;
// It would be the code if I use a regular HashMap instead of ConcurrentHashMap
    /*Event event = map.get(key);       

    // Map does not contain this service.method, create an Event for the first     time.
    if(event == null){
        event = new Event();            
        map.put(key, event);

        // Map already contains this key, just adjust the numbers.
    }else{
        // Modify the object fields
    }*/
    //}

    // Make it thread-safe using CHM
    Event newEvent = new Event();
    Event existingEvent= map.putIfAbsent(key, newEvent); 

    if(existingEvent!=null && existingEvent!=newEvent){
        // Modify the object fields
}       

private void saveEntries(){

    Map<String, List<Event>> engineCalls = null;
    try {           

        engineCalls = new HashMap<String, List<Event>>();
        List<Event> events = null;

// How can I achieve therad safety here w/o applying any lock?
        //synchronized(lock){
            if(!vendor1Calls.isEmpty()){
                events = new ArrayList<Event>();
                events.addAll(vendor1Calls.values());
                engineCalls.put(vendor1, events);
                vendor1Calls.clear();
            }
            if(!vendor2Calls.isEmpty()){
                events = new ArrayList<Event>();
                events.addAll(vendor2Calls.values());
                engineCalls.put(vendor2, events);
                vendor2Calls.clear();
            }
        //}

// logICalls() saves the events in the DB.          
        DBHandle.logCalls(engineCalls);
    } catch (Throwable t) {         
    } finally {
        if(engineCalls!=null){
            engineCalls.clear();
        }                       
    }   
}
```

}

Comment: You accept the answer by clicking the grey checkmark to the left of an answer. Don't accept the answer if it doesn't solve your problem, though, peer pressure notwithstanding.

Comment: Yes, I suggest you go to http://stackoverflow.com/users/1052348/bluesky?tab=questions, click every link, and click the checkmark next to the answer that best solved your problem.

PS you can accept an answer you made yourself to your own question.

Comment: crossposted [here](https://forums.oracle.com/forums/thread.jspa?threadID=2431482&tstart=0), and you can make it atomic using CHM features alone.

Comment: I know this is an old question, but I don't understand why you are using a map for something that seems inherently like a queue in the first place. You could add log entries to a concurrent queue, and then in save entries look at the size of the queue and remove that many from the front of the queue and write them. Because you just look at the size once, it doesn't matter if more are added while you're saving them; they will be left for next time. Sorry if I've misunderstood your purpose.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> However, when I read from it and then remove all entries by clear()
>   method, I want no other thread writes to map while I’m in the process
>   of reading the map contents and then removing them.

I think what you're trying to say is that you don't really care about strictly locking the maps. Instead, you only really care about the loss of any log entries between the vender1Calls.values() and vendor1Calls.clear(), correct?

In that is the case, I can imagine that you can replace

```
events.addAll(vendor1Calls.values());
vendor1Calls.clear();
```

with this in saveEntries:

```
for (Iterator<Event> iter = vendor1Calls.values().iterator(); iter.hasNext(); ) {
    Event e = iter.next();
    events.add(e);
    iter.remove();
}
```

That way, you only remove the Events that you added to the events List already. You can still write to the vendor1Calls maps while saveEntries() is still executing, but the iterator skips the values added.

Comment: It may actually iterate over values added in the meantime, but there are no guarantees.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. How using Iterator makes it thread safe? How can I make sure that not 2 threads at the same time, iterating thru the values() of maps and while one performing: Event e = iter.next(); the other thread is not performing: iter.remove(); ? Also my goal was to lock the entire map that no other thread writes to it while I'm in the process of reading from map, b/c what would happen to the entries added to the map when I'm in the process of iterating thru them?

Comment: I assumed from the fact that since you used a timer to call saveEntries(), that saveEntries() is private, and that you have no other code, you will not have more than one thread iterating over either vendor1Calls or vendor2Calls and possibly call remove on them.

Comment: The ones that are written while being iterated may or may not be saved ("Iterators and Enumerations return elements reflecting the state of the hash table at some point at or since the creation of the iterator/enumeration."), but there's one thing for certain: absolutely no entry will be lost, because those that are removed by calling iter.remove() in saveEntries() have already been added to the events ArrayList.

Comment: keep in mind that iter.remove() removes the element that was returned by iter.next(). don't expect that something will be added in the spot occupied by your current position in the iterator and that iter.remove() will remove that by mistake.

Comment: You are right, saveEntries() is private, so only the timer thread would iterate thru them and remove them from map. But the very same maps that are being iterating thru by timer thread in saveEntries() are being modified in the log() method by so many other threads at the same time so I was not sure what is going to happen to them? I guess its safe to say that since I'm not removing them, then I pick them up in the next 5 minutes and save them in db? But I'm not sure whether it happens or those entries would get lost. If that's in fact the case, then does CopyOnWriteArrayList helps?

Comment: One more thing: from Java docs: Similarly, Iterators and Enumerations return elements reflecting the state of the hash table at some point at or since the creation of the iterator/enumeration. They do not throw ConcurrentModificationException. However, iterators are designed to be used by only one thread at a time. Does that mean that an Iterator is therad safe? As far as I know they are not necessarily thread safe...

Comment: when the javadoc mentions Iterators, they mean Iterator instances (objects). the Iterator instance used here is a local variable and never is assigned as an instance variable of the Logging class or any other class. hence, you never have to worry about thread safety for it as it never gets released to other threads. when other threads call values().iterator(), they create new instances of Iterator and don't reuse the ones you are already using.

and yes, entries that miss the save will be saved the next time saveEntries() is called.

Comment: @blueSky You should never really share Iterators between threads.  Imagine if you have two threads calling `next` on an Iterator of a CHM of size 1.  If both threads call `hasNext` at the same time the iterator may return true for both.  If both threads see `true` and invoke `next` both threads may get a result or one may get `NoSuchElementException`

Comment: @JohnVint: Although what you said is correct, but please go thru the responses from Kevin. I think it would be safe to use Iterator here b/c its being called by one thread only: timer thread. I could use Collections.synchronizedMap or just a regular HashMap with synchronized block, but I chose CHM b/c of performance issues and then I tried to achieve thread safety. Please let me know whether you think the Kevin's reasoning may not be correct.

Comment: @blueSky I have.  I only commented because you noted that `iterators are designed to be used by only one thread at a time` which led me to believe you would share them (which you may not be).   That being said if you are ok with the TimerThread going through and possibly seeing elements in the Map after the initial iterator was created then this should work - But obviously does not guarantee atomicity.  Iterators are as thread safe (assuming a thread-local Iterator instance) as is the CHM.

Comment: I assume what's happening here is: TimerThread goes thru, performs: Iterator<Event> iter = vendorCalls.values().iterator(); which gets an snapshot of what I have in vendorCalls at that moment, and then iterates thru them, fills out the Events list and then removes that entry from vendorCalls; so it does not care about the entries that are being added at that moment from other threads in the log() method; so it does not throw ConcurrentModificationEx either. At the end of for loop, when iter finished iterating thru its snapshot, I save the contents of the Events into db and it repeats every 5..

Comment: ...every 5 minutes and then I save what added in the maps next time I call saveEntries() method. So when you mentions: "if you are ok with the TimerThread going through and possibly seeing elements in the Map after the initial iterator was created then this should work": what problems it might cause?

Comment: @blueSky `Iterator<Event> iter = vendorCalls.values().iterator();` Returns a view of the Map itself and not a snapshot.  The difference in the two is that a snapshot is what the contents are exactly the moment of invocation.  A view is the contents of the Map at Iterator's method invocation.  Meaning the Map can have a size of 10 when you invoke `.iterator()` and a size of 15 at some `next` call.  But the difference is not guaranteed.

Comment: But obviously does not guarantee atomicity: that's right but I think it would be safe here b/c as mentioned I pick the rest of entries the next time I call saveEntries() method. Please let me know if I'm missing a point here.

Comment: It may cause no problems at all.  But it is worth realizing that the Iterator may actually iterate over the course of the method more then the initial size of the CHM upon `iterator()` invocation.  It appears it wouldn't cause any issue but it is worth thinking through to ensure it will work

Comment: "Returns a view of the Map itself and not a snapshot. The difference in the two is that a snapshot is what the contents are exactly the moment of invocation. A view is the contents of the Map at Iterator's method invocation. Meaning the Map can have a size of 10 when you invoke .iterator() and a size of 15 at some next call. But the difference is not guaranteed." If that's the case, I might end up with a loop that never ends! B/c as it actually might add entries to it much faster than I remove them! So is there anyway that I obtain a snapshot or make it atomic somehow w/o using locks?

Comment: Thanks everybody for the time and responses. Very helpful. I'll think about it... looks like making it atomic is not an option here. I will choose bet. synchronizedMap or just iterating thru. Thanks again.

Answer (score 3):

Without any external synchronization you cannot achieve this with a CHM.  The Iterator views returned are weakly consistent which means the contents of the Map can change while you are actually iterating over it.

It appears you would need to use a `Collections.synchronizedMap` to get the functionality you are looking for.

Edit to make my point more clear:

To achieve this with a `synchronizedMap` You would first have to `synchronize` on the Map and then you can iterate or copy the contents into another map an then clear.

```
Map map = Collections.synchronizedMap(new HashMap());

public void work(){
  Map local = new HashMap();
  synchronized(map){
     local.putAll(map);
     map.clear();
  }
  //do work on local instance 
}
```

Instead of the `local` instance, as I mentioned, you can `iterate + remove` similar to @Kevin Jin's answer.

Comment: `syncronizedMap`'s iterators are useless for the job as they fall apart in the face of concurrent changes to the map. On the other hand, there's nothing wrong with the CHM iterator catching any later entries, it might even be better since more entries will be saved and removed from the map.

Comment: @Marko Topolnik I was speaking on terms of atomicity.  I should have made it more obvious that he would have to `synchronize` on the Map itself.  This obviously has the side effect of performance degradation but if he needs to have no threads updating while another thread iterates then clears there would be no other way to do it.  That however may not be the case from his needs.

Comment: @JohnVint: since Iterator does not give me a snapshot, then is this possible that I end up with a loop that never ends! B/c as threads actually might add entries to the map much faster than I remove them! So is there anyway that I obtain a snapshot or make it atomic somehow w/o using locks?

Comment: In theory it can but in practice its unlikely. You can throttle byt getting the size before iterating and if a count exceeds you can break early. That being said an infinite loop isnt something i would worry about

Comment: Thanks everybody for the time and responses. Very helpful. I'll think about it... looks like making it atomic is not an option here. I will choose bet. synchronizedMap or just iterating thru. Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

An atomic version of this example is shown [in this thread](https://forums.oracle.com/forums/thread.jspa?threadID=2431482&tstart=0) (using only the features in ConcurrentMap).

Answer (score 0):

My best suggestion would be to use a [ReadWriteLock](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/locks/ReentrantReadWriteLock.html) but as you specifically state that you don't want to use any locks (btw `ConcurrentHashMap` will probably use them internally) you could try the following.

Use an [AtomicReference](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/atomic/AtomicReference.html) to each of your maps and when the time comes to log their contents use [getAndSet](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/atomic/AtomicReference.html#getAndSet%28V%29) to replace the old map with a brand new empty one.

You now have a Map with exclusive use that you can iterate across and clear as much as you like. Unfortunately there is one small problem (that using a lock will get rid of) and that is if another thread is in the process of adding to the map at the time you swap it out with an empty one. You could perhaps add a delay at this point in the hope of waiting long enough for the other thread to finish what it was doing. Perhaps there is some internal functionality of a `ConcurrentHashMap` you can use to wait until everyone has finished with it.

Answer (score 0):

The following code uses a [persistent map](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Persistent_data_structure) from the [functional java](http://functionaljava.org/) project. It uses more memory, but is (AFAIK :) safe to use by multiple threads. The only mutable value in the `AtomicReference` and it is updated with a *compare-and-set*. The map and event are *immutable*, and hence thread-safe. Also, instead of clearing the map, I replace the reference to it.

```
import fj.F;
import fj.Ord;
import fj.data.TreeMap;

import java.util.*;
import java.util.concurrent.atomic.AtomicReference;

public class Logging
{
    // Event is immutable
    private static class Event
    {
        // updates are done by creating new values
        Event update(String key)
        {
            return new Event();
        }
    }

    // Refactored code pertaining to one vendor into a separate class.
    private static class EngineLogger
    {
        public final String vendor;
        private final AtomicReference<TreeMap<String, Event>> mapRef =
                new AtomicReference<TreeMap<String, Event>>(TreeMap.<String, Event>empty(Ord.stringOrd));

        private EngineLogger(String vendor)
        {
            this.vendor = vendor;
        }

        public void log(String service, String method)
        {
            final String key = service + "." + method;
            boolean updated = false;
            while (! updated)
            {
                // get the current value of the map
                TreeMap<String, Event> currMap = mapRef.get();

                // create an updated value of the map, which is the current map plus info about the new key
                TreeMap<String, Event> newMap = currMap.update(key, new F<Event, Event>()
                {
                    @Override
                    public Event f(Event event)
                    {
                        // Modify the object fields of event, if the map contains the key
                        return event.update(key);
                    }
                    // create a new event if the map does not contain the key
                }, new Event());

                // compare-and-set the new value in .. repeat until this succeeds
                updated = mapRef.compareAndSet(currMap, newMap);
            }
        }

        public List<Event> reset()
        {
            /* replace the reference with a new map */
            TreeMap<String, Event> oldMap = mapRef.getAndSet(TreeMap.<String, Event>empty(Ord.stringOrd));

            /* use the old map to generate the list */
            return new ArrayList<Event>(oldMap.toMutableMap().values());
        }
    }

    private static Logging instance;
    private static long delay = 5 * 60 * 1000;
    private final Timer timer;

    private final EngineLogger vendor1 = new EngineLogger("vendor1");
    private final EngineLogger vendor2 = new EngineLogger("vendor2");

    private Logging()
    {
        timer = new Timer();
        timer.schedule(new TimerTask()
        {
            public void run()
            {
                try
                {
                    saveEntries();
                }
                catch (Throwable t)
                {
                    timer.cancel();
                    timer.purge();
                }
            }
        }, 0, delay);
    }

    public static synchronized Logging getInstance()
    {
        if (instance == null)
        {
            instance = new Logging();
        }
        return instance;
    }

    public void log(String engine, String service, String method)
    {
        if (vendor1.vendor.equals(engine))
        {
            vendor1.log(service, method);
        }
        else if (vendor2.vendor.equals(engine))
        {
            vendor2.log(service, method);
        }
    }

    private void saveEntries()
    {
        Map<String, List<Event>> engineCalls = new HashMap<String, List<Event>>();
        engineCalls.put(vendor1.vendor, vendor1.reset());
        engineCalls.put(vendor2.vendor, vendor2.reset());
        DBHandle.logCalls(engineCalls);
    }
}
```

Comment: Although may not be suitable for my purpose b/c of memory usage, but very helpful. Thanks so much for sharing.

Comment: @blueSky Thinking more, I realize that this solution scales poorly. The _CAS_ in `log` method will fail even when different threads modify `Event`s for different keys.

Comment: Thanks for the update. I was not able to use it b/c of memory issue. Its always great to know what's out there :)